# Old option chain symbols

Tags: investing, options

I am going through my investment history, but there are a lot of option trades that don't make sense. For example, in 2009, "OZC Jan 22 2011 25.0 Put" was the $25 put for QQQ expiring in 2011. I was able to find this one with trial and error, but how can I find the underlying for all of them in general?

I am looking for someplace that I can lookup OZC and find that it corresponds to QQQ.

Comment: Where do you see that? Maybe it's just bad historical data from your broker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2010, the OCC enacted Options Symbology Initiative (OSI) which expanded option symbols from  5 characters to 22 characters.  In both cases, the option's root symbol was the stock's symbol unless the option was adjusted due to a corporate action such as a fractional split, a special dividend, etc.

The OCC provides a few months of [option bulletins](https://infomemo.theocc.com/infomemo/search) here.  It also offers a search function.  The CBOE used to have a similar feature but I don't know if they still do.  And you can also google the root symbol to see if you can find a story/link.

Comment: Thank you! The OCC link had the information. I had been to the CBOE before posting, and it wasn't there. Likewise, Google searches didn't turn up the answers.